# Testing Successful retrieval using OAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

I am working on a Rails web application. I am using Oauth to authenticate and i have a ruby API that interfaces with an api(JSON) to  retrieve information. I want to test this using RSPEC(if i can successfully authenticate and retrieve) and need some help on how i could go about this ? .